# How do I merge information without duplicates?

Tags: sql

i have 4 tables that look like this: The first table 'Orders'

```
orderNumber  orderDate   requiredDate  shippedDate   status     comments   customerNumber
10166        21/10/2003  30/10/2003    27/10/2003    Shipped    NULL       462
10321        4/11/2004   12/11/2004    7/11/2004     Shipped    NULL       462
10167        23/10/2003  30/10/2003                  Cancelled  Cancelled  448
10291        8/9/2004    12/9/2004     14/9/2004     Shipped    NULL       448
```

Second table 'OrderDetails'

```
orderNumber  productCode  quantityOrdered  priceEach  orderLineNumber
10166        s18_1234     43               136        1
10166        s18_1235     26               72         2
10321        s18_4524     19               5          1
10321        s18_4522     14               5          2
10167        s18_1662     34               102        1
10167        s18_4757     12               67         2
10291        s18_3894     10               67         1
10291        s18_3515     50               67         2
```

Third table 'Payments'

```
customerNumber  checkNumber  paymentDate  amount
462             JM555205     8/11/2003    7720
462             PW176846     27/11/2004   165
448             AZ384638     30/9/2004    4020
```

Fourth table 'Customers'

```
customerNumber CustomerName
462            Gregg
448            Bryan
```

With this 4 tables, i hope to come up with a SQL statement that can show the orderNumber, total payment for that order, status, and amount received. Something like the table below in order to track the amount still owed/cancelled by customers and also amount that has already been received.

```
orderNumber  totalAmount  status     amountReceived
10166        7720         Shipped    7720
10321        165          Shipped    165
10167        4272         Cancelled  0
10291        4020         Shipped    4020
```

Bit of a long question, appreciate any response. Thank you very much

Comment: You forgot the SQL you attempted.

Comment: How would you, as a human, apply a payment against an order/order line? There is no key between those tables, so some logic will need to be provided like "I apply the check amount against the oldest unpaid order line item that occurred before the date of the check"

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this work - I only did this in 5 minutes and havent fully looked through it but could be a starting template for you.

```
SELECT 
      ordr.orderNumber, 
      sum(pts.Amount) as [Total Amount], 
      ordr.status, 
      sum(ordrDet.quantityOrdered * ordrDet.priceEach) as [Amount Recieved],
      sum(pts.Amount - (ordrDet.quantityOrdered * ordrDet.priceEach)) as [Amount Owed]
FROM Orders ordr
             LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ordrDet on ordr.orderNumber = ordrDet.orderNumber
             LEFT JOIN Payment pts on pts.customerNumber = ordr.customerNumber
GROUP BY ordr.orderNumber, ordr.status
```